# How is Charter Spectrum doing this in my browser?

Tags: google-chrome, security, xss

I know this is not a programming question and it could be open ended. However, I feel like I can get this most help here.

Is the image below cross-site scripting or a result of net-neutrality? If so, what can do to get them out of my browser?

So far I have noticed this on my computer, my wife's computer which has better security on it, and it is happening to other people I know.

It happens randomly in my google chrome browser. I have not seen it in FF or Edge but I don't use those much. It will also occur on different websites. The copyright is 2016 but it is happening now (2019). I would think this was an annoying ad but it has my name in it, and it occurs when I have to pay the bill. Also just another observation, it seems to happen on HTTP sites, not HTTPS but I could be wrong.

Any information to get Charter out would be helpful. Please don't say use TOR

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably [DNS hijacking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_hijacking).

To mitigate, you could try:

- Not using your ISP's DNS servers. Try OpenDNS or similar.
- DNS over HTTPS
- The HTTPS Everywhere browser extension, which might help reduce it
- a VPN

Comment: Thank you, I will have to look into my home network and apply the changes. You gave me a good list to start from